# Open files in new tabs in Kate

Tags: editor, contextmenu, windows-11, kde-plasma, kate

I installed the kate editor for Windows using the installer:

https://cdn.kde.org/ci-builds/utilities/kate/master/windows/

Now when I open files via the windows context menu, kate opens these files in a new window:

[image]

How do I change the default behaviour of kate to open the files in tabs within the session I have already opened? I only want to have one instance of kate open at the same time with all the files I currently use.